# Android Linear/Relative Layout - how to "auto size" object in the middle (3 objects)

Tags: android, uitableview, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have two cases with Linear (also tried Relative) layout in android. The one happens for horizontal and the other for vertical. Lets start with the horizontal:

it is something like:

```
<LinearLayout ... >   
    <Button ...  layout:gravity = "left" layout:width = "wrap_content"/>
    <TextView ... layout:width = ??????? />
    <Image  .... layout:gravity = "right" layout:width = "wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Well , I want the button to stay at the left, the image to stay at the right(stick to the end , not just right of the text view) and the textview to (probably with an autowidth or whatever) to stay in the middle. If I put in textview width = "fill/match_parent it sends the image out of the screen. If I put wrap_content, then the image does not stay at the right of the screen.  I have also tried relative layout without success.

Same case in vertical , where I have  something like:

```
<LinearLayout ...>
    <LinearLayout .... layout:height = "wrap_content" layout:gravity= "top" />
    <ListView layout:height = ???????>
    <LinearLayout ... layout:height = "wrap_content" layout:gravity = "bottom" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Same requirement here. I want the first L.layout to stay on top, List view auto size between them and the 2nd Linear layout to stay at the bottom. (Imagine I'm trying to create a view that looks like a UITableView in iPhone that has a NavigationBar, the list of items and a ToolBar at the bottom. Fist LinearLayout is the NavigationBar, the LIst view are the cells and the second LinearLayout is the ToolBar).

Any suggestions? Would prefer the xml solutions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can simply done by using RelativeLayout here we go.

**Horizontal alignment**

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">  

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="something"
    />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button" />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Vertical alignment**

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_top"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear_top"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linear_bottom" />

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried something almost like this last night and it didn't work. I'll try it exactly like this and we'll see. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For your second requirement use `layout_weight` for list view

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
   <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
   <ListView 
        android:layout_height ="0dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_layout"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottm_layout" />
   <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hmmm..I did this but without the wight at the middle object. I'll try it when I go home.

Comment: What makes ListView to come below from LinearLayout at top when List having rows which covers full screen?

Comment: @RajaReddyP what about "below"?

Answer (score 0):

You may try **TableLayout** instead LinearLayout with **Stretch Column** is 1 (Columns in Table LAyout are indexed base 0).

First column is your button.

Second column is your textview.

Third column is your image.

You can google about example or see [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html).

**Updated:**

You can see this for clearer:

```
<RelativeLayout>
     <!-- This is Header-->
     <LinearLayout
          .....
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
     </LinearLayout>

     <!-- This is your table-->
     <TableLayout
          .....
          android:stretchColumns = 1>
          <TableRow>
               <Button>
                .....
               </Button>

               <TextView>
                .....
               </TextView>

               <ImageView>
                .....
               </ImageView>
          </TableRow>
     </TableLayout>

     <!-- This is Footer-->
     <LinearLayout
          ..... 
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
     </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```