# I need help getting my .XML layout to fit the screen on an old Zebra device

Tags: android, visual-studio

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_bg4"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:showDividers="beginning"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_Background">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_trans"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:padding="10dp">
                   <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView_Site"
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                    android:gravity="left|center"
                    android:text="Site"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/WSMediumTextBold" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView_Code"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left|center"
                    android:text="Code"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/WSMediumTextBold" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView_Name"
                    android:layout_width="220dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left|center"
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/WSMediumTextBold" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView_Main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It currently looks like this on the Zebra device:

[image]

I need to change it so that the "Name" column isn't cut off at the bottom of the screen. Any advice/ help on how to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "fill_parent" as the value for "android:layout_width" in the Code column.  According to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/11790323/16052620 it should then size to fill the gap between the two fixed width TextViews.

Comment: I'll give that a go. Thank you.